# Debug ios share error message

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have trouble with the Facebook iOS share method described here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/

When I login with Facebook and share for the first time it works. After that I am getting the following error message:

[image]

I have no idea how to debug it and where I can look up this error code.

Anybody can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I found a bug report https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/169352693201670?browse=search_504e55a89e7af1b86045526 which states that you need to use the old deprecated headers for now.